# Connecting NAS to raspberry Pi via proxy-arp

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, nas

This might be a stupid question, but I just wanted to make sure I don't invest time into something that doesn't solve my problem eventually:

My home network contains a router/WiFi access point, a NAS that holds some media and serves as a  backup device and cloud server, and a raspberry Pi that is used as a media player using kodi. The Pi connects to the router via WiFi.

Ideally, I would be able to stream files from the NAS on the Pi, however, if I connect the NAS to the router via Ethernet, the WiFi speed is insufficient to stream high resolution media on the pi.

My idea was now to use a proxy-arp configuration on my Pi to connect the NAS via Ethernet directly to the Pi.

Would this...

- ...improve streaming speed due to the fact that the two devices are now connected directly and via cable? Or would the data still have to pass through the router (and hence the slow WiFi), as this remains the dns server?
- ...still allow other network devices to access the NAS as if it was directly connected to the router?

Comment: It seems like the Wi-Fi speed is almost certainly the limiting factor. Do you know what the bitrate of the media you're trying to stream is?

Comment: Yes, I agree, that's why I am looking for a way to avoid streaming over WiFi. I usually start to experience stuttering and lags when the bitrate exceeds 10 MB/s.

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding something, but what about just using a normal wired network with the Pi?

Comment: Yes, that would of course be possible, but my router has no free Ethernet port left and I was trying to avoid the cable across the living room.

Comment: What about just buying a cheap unmanaged switch?

Comment: To increase the number of available Ethernet ports? Yes, also possible, but would still bring the downside of placing a cable through the living room. You are right in pointing out that there are definitely simpler solutions, but I am just curious whether the above might be an elegant solution that makes best use of the existing hardware.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103365/discussion-between-jmy1000-and-niclas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: yes, it works just as intended. I followed this guide:
https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections